What is the direct role of exchangeability in ensuring coverage in conformal prediction?
I was wondering how exchangeability directly relates to the proof of the coverage guarantee in conformal prediction. In most papers I have seen, usually they say that by exchangeability the order of the scores is uniformally distributed (assuming no duplicate scores) and they continue from there. Alternatively I thought maybe because they are using the empirical quantile from the available data points, due to exchangeability somehow the real quantile is very close to the approximation. This might be due to the fact that the expected value of the empirical distribution is equal to the real one. But I could be wrong. I really would like to see direct proof or any resources that would help me see the link between exchangeability and the coverage guarantee without skipping steps 
I would greatly appreciate it!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Maybe if I had some idea which proposition is proved by the proof you're talking about and what the proof is, then I could say something about this. Exchangeability of a sequence $X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots$ of random variables means that if you list them in a different order, then the sequence still has the same probability distribution. A consequence is that if the values of the random variables are real numbers or members of some other linearly ordered set, then when the random variables are sorted into increasing order, all orders are equally probable.

An urn contains 10 red and 6 blue marbles. Marbles are sampled WITHOUT replacement, so the resulting random colors are NOT independent. (1) What is the conditional probability that the second one drawn is red, given that the first was red? (2) What is the conditional probability that the first was red, given that the second was red? Even very intelligent students sometimes fail to see immediately that it doesn't matter which was first and which was second. But if you want to compute the variance of the number of red marbles in the first four draws, then knowing that they are$,\ldots\qquad$

$\ldots,$exchangeable makes that a lot easier: If $X_k\in{0,1}$ is the number of red marbles on the $k$ trial, then $\operatorname{var}(X_1+ X_2+X_3+X_4)$ $=\operatorname{var}(X_1) + \cdots + \operatorname{var}(X_4) + 2\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_2) + \cdots,$ and the four variances are equal to each other and the six covariances are equal to each other.

Thank you so much for your comments! and sorry for the late response! So for example in D.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.07511 (Gentle Introduction to CP) , the proof for the upper bound claims that due to the exchangeability of the data the upper bound holds, using the implication that exchangeability implies that the ranks have a uniform distribution. This has been shown a bit more in detail in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.06095. I'm not sure if there are any other resources that show that with much detail as well.

Alternatively, since the empirical quantile seems to achieve the coverage, I was wondering if this property could also be proven by somehow relating the true quantile to the computed one.
